# How do I need to adjust Spring's Transaction Management configuration when moving to >= spring-tx-5.3.0?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc, spring-transactions

**Problem**

After upgrading from Spring Boot 2.3.12.RELEASE to >= 2.4.0 (from spring-tx-5.2.15 to 5.3+), I get the following error reported from SQL Server JDBC driver:

> c.m.sqlserver.jdbc.internals.TDS.Reader  : TDSReader@30
> (ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId:
> ff3ee928-1a1c-4d97-b4b7-f13d87f4d35c) got unexpected value in TDS
> response at offset:7992
>
> c.m.s.jdbc.internals.SQLServerException  : ***
> SQLException:ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId:
> ff3ee928-1a1c-4d97-b4b7-f13d87f4d35c
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TDS protocol
> stream is not valid. The TDS protocol stream is not valid.

**Background**

My code calls two stored procedures. One is to establish an application session on the DB and the other is to get varbinary(max). With Spring Boot >= 2.4.0, I get the error while reading the bytes of the varbinary(max):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes=CarServiceApplication.class)
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER, transactionManager="carTransactionManager")
@Slf4j
public class HoldingRepositoryTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private SessionRepository sessionRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private CarRepository carRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private AppProperties appLogin;

    @Test
    public void test() throws SQLException {
        sessionRepository.getSession(appLogin.getUser(), appLogin.getPassword());
        LocalDate july5Of2016 = LocalDate.of(2016, 7, 5);
        Blob reportData = carRepository.getReportData("VIN1234", july5Of2016);
        byte[] reportDataBytes = reportData.getBytes(1, (int) reportData.length()); //error occurs here
        assertThat(reportData, notNullValue());
    }
}
```

Here is my transaction manager:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"com.example.car.repository"}, 
    entityManagerFactoryRef="carEntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "carTransactionManager") 
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class CarDatabaseConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean carEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, 
            DataSource dataSource) {       
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("com.example.car.domain")
                .persistenceUnit("car")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager carTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory carEntityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(carEntityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

**What I've tried**

If I remove `@Transactional`, I get the same TDS error in Spring 2.3.12.RELEASE. So, I believe with versions >= 2.4.0 @Transactional is being ignored for some reason.

**Question**

How should I change my transaction config to avoid this error and have this run as it did in 2.3.12.RELEASE?

**Update**

I moved the call to the getReportData stored procedure into a different method (in the service layer) and annotated as `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER,  transactionManager ="carTransactionManager")`.  This resolved the issue. It also works with `Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED`. The key seems to be putting this in a different component method outside of the test class.

Does anyone know why that would make the difference and why the behavior changed moving to Spring Boot >= 2.4.0 (i.e., from spring-tx-5.2.15 to 5.3+)?

**Update 2**

I turned on transaction logging:

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.orm.jpa: trace
    org.springframework.transaction: trace
```

When running my integration test, I can see that a transaction is created for 'getReportData` when placed in my service layer"

> TRACE 2424 --- [           main] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor
> : Completing transaction for
> [com.example.car.service.CarService.getReportData]

but no transaction is created for my test method:

> TRACE 2424 --- [           main] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor
> : No need to create transaction for
> [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getSession]:
> This method is not transactional.

So `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER,  transactionManager ="carTransactionManager")` creates transactional method outside of `@SpringBootTest` method but is ignored in a `@SpringBootTest` test class.

Comment: Have you tried without a `Propagation.NEVER`?

Comment: @M.Deinum - Yes. My integration test is set to `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER, transactionManager="carTransactionManager")` That works in 2.3.12.RELEASE but not >=2.4.0

Comment: As stated have you tried **without `Propagation.NEVER`**... Not without `@Transactional`.

Comment: @M.Deinum - Sorry for misreading... I just tried and `sessionRepository.getSession` hangs for a bit when removing `Propagation.NEVER`, `@Transactional( transactionManager="carTransactionManager")`. Then it throws: `org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults; SQL [Car_pReportData];` .  This is due to sessionRepository.getSession return null (i.e., no session is established). Therefore, Car_pReportData fails

Comment: @M.Deinum - I called the getSession stored procedure using `Propagation.NEVER` and the getReportData (Car_pReportData) stored procedure using Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED` and it works. I wonder why this worked vs just having both in `Propagation.NEVER`. I'll update my OP.

Comment: If you want to share the resource, as that appears what you want, you need to have a transaction surrounding both. If you don't there is no guarantee that you will re-use the same underlying jdbc connection.  With propagation level NEVER if there is no transaction you will also not get a transaction. Hence my suggestion of removing the `Propagation.NEVER` which would yield the default `REQUIRED` which would create a connection.

Comment: @M.Deinum - Thank you for helping me on this. Much appreciated. I didn't write the "getSession" stored procedure and don't have access to view it. If I call it within a `@Transactional(propagation = Progagation.REQUIRED)` method, it hangs for a bit and then fails to acquire a session. For the other stored procedure that is called by "getReportData", it appears that it needs to be called within `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER )`. My Spring app logs tell me that although this is `Propagation.NEVER` the call still runs in a txn. I'm not sure why. I updated the OP with this info.